# Bulging on distinctive lengths along the X-Axis (on all layers)

Tags: marlin, y-axis, x-axis, carriage

I have massive print-quality issues on my Anycubic Vyper.

As you can see on the first, third and fourth image, there is some sort of bulging or shifting happening. The issue seems to be related to the x-Axis.
I took the printer apart and inspected the whole axis. No issues were found. The carriage moves uniformly, until it enters the area where the bulging happens. Then it suddenly has a lot less resistance and it feels as if it "slides" into a small detent. I can't feel any issues on the extrusion though.

I can't feel these "detents" when the belts are properly tightened and I move the carriage by hand. There is no sudden massive resistance or anything.

I have tried all sort of different levels of tightness of the eccentric nut. Ranging from stock (problem was there out of the box) to loose to really tight. The problem stays.
I have also re-oriented the bowden tube, it didn't change anything.

The first major bulge is slightly to the right of the center. Left of it no problems were experienced.

What's the issue and how can I fix it?

[image: highlightet area on first layer]

[image: overall printer]

[image: massive problem]

[image: massive problem]

Comment: Have you held a (straight metal) ruler alongside the aluminum extrusion profile. If you slice the "wall" at a different location on the build plate, where is the bulge then located?

Comment: Are the bulges evenly spaced? If so, what is the spacing between their peaks?

Comment: Looks like the spacing could be exactly the circumference of the roller wheel. I wonder whether the roller wheel shafts are perpendicular to the X-Axis.

Comment: Considering the use of a bounty, you are in dire need of an answer, could you please comment on the comments? Or, possibly add more information since there is almost a week past since the bounty was issued.

Comment: (1) The bulging only appears at these two X-axis locations, not periodically along the whole axis. The Extrusion itself doesn't seem to have any irregularities I could measure with a ruler or see with my naked eye looking down the length. BUT the problem appears very precisely at the same location each time.
The Y-position (i.e. the position of the bed) does not matter.
I have resorted to avoid printing in that location to avoid artifacts in the part, which obviously isn't the best solution...

Comment: (2) What I will try to do when I have the time is to swap out the carriage wheels and bolts and see if this changes anything. 
Thanks for everyone who pitched in, but it seems that this kind of issue is not very common...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try greasing the wheels. I've had a similar effect on a printer that I hadn't used for years. After reassembling it, the x carriage moved freely except at a few points, which were always at the same position. I had to apply more force to get past these points. I don't know whether that's your problem, but it sounds like. I greased the wheel's axles with a drop of oil at each wheel, and now it's running fine again.

Comment: The wheels have closed cage bearings, why oil them? Please explain.

Comment: I can only tell you that applying some oil to my wheels' bearings solved this issue for me.